# Django multi-language site, setting the locale

Tags: django, django-i18n

I have a django-site which supports German, English, (Swiss-)French and (Swiss-)Italian. When I output a datetime-object, the used language for strftime() is always english. How can I correctly change this?
Is it possible to set the locale dynamic to the current language?

In my settings I have:

```
USE_L10N = True
USE_I18N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('Deutsch')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('it', _('Italian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Zurich'
```

Thanks for any hints!